# Where is the configuration file?

Tags: bitcoind, ubuntu, bitcoin.conf

This is strange!

The [documentation](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#testing-applications) on running the Bitcoin daemon on a Ubuntu machine is clear. The configuration file is supposed to be at `$HOME/.bitcoin/` location. And yet, I cannot locate it! I looked for clues at `/etc`, `/var`, and `/tmp` too; nothing there. In fact, in one of my attempts to launch the daemon, the `debug.log` (created at `$HOME/.bitcoin/`) did call out the configuration file to be `$HOME/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` but the file itself wouldn't be listed. Permissions? - I don't know.

Can you please tell me where to look for this file?

This is on Ubuntu-16.04, 64-bit where bitcoin was installed via [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin/+archive/ubuntu/bitcoin/+packages). Yes; I am working with Bitcoin code for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration file is definitely in `$HOME/.bitcoin/`. If you cannot see it, the most likely explanation is that you have not created it. Just use your favorite text editor to do so. As far as I can tell, `bitcoind -daemon` will run without `bitcoin.conf` being present and you will still get the message 'Using config file /home/user/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf' in `debug.log` even when no file exists.

Comment: "As far as I can tell, bitcoind -daemon will run without bitcoin.conf being present" That helps; thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Is it possible to query the running `bitcoind` process to ask it where the `bitcoin.conf` file it's reading from is located, if any?